# Entity Framework : invalid object name "TableName1"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with Entity Framework, I think I have a problem defining the one to many mapping, but I can't seem to find it.

When I try to save my changes and add my info to the database I get the following error:

> Invalid object name 'Results1'

With `Results` being the name of one of my tables, for some reasons it's adding the 1 at the end.

I have a `Results` table where I need to store an `Id` and several other information regarding results of a test, then I have a `Reasons` table where I need to store several reasons for each `Result.Id`.

This is how I defined the `Reasons` class:

```
public class Reasons
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ResultId { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public Results Results { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the `Results` class:

```
public class Results
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     //Other properties

     public ICollection<Reasons> Reasons { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `Reasons` configuration:

```
configurator.
             Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

configurator
            .HasRequired<Results>(s => s.Results)
            .WithMany(g => g.Reasons)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.IdResults);
```

Solved: the only problem was that the "Reasons" and the "Results" class did not completely match the data model. Once that was repaired the problem disappeared.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use singular names for classes and reference properties (`Reason.Result`) and only plural names for collections (`Result.Reasons`). That said, did you try to configure the table names explicitly? And does `Reason.Result` point to the same `Result` class as the class you show (it doesn't seem to)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your foreign key in `Reasons` class from `ResultId` to `ResultsId` or explicitly use `[ForeignKey("Results")]` attribute above it. From [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

> EF makes a property as foreign key property when its name matches with
> the primary key property of a related entity

In your case it should be:

```
// Foreign key for Results
public int ResultsId { get; set; }
// Navigation property
public Results Results { get; set; }
```

2. Remove your configuration instructions. There is no need to use fluent api to configure your database scheme since entity framework will do it by self. Here are examples [how to configure](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) one to many relations via code first approach

As was answered in comments it is a good practice to use singular name for a model in order to use plural form for navigational properties.